# c# wpf - concurrent licensing user timeout

Tags: c#, timeout

I wanted to implement concurrent licensing into my software so that there would not be more than x users logged in at one time.

Every time a user logs in, I'm going to insert into an sql table that will hold the currently running sessions.

I will check if the total count is over the limit and if not, let the user log in.

How do I check this sql table every specific amount of time in order to get rid of sessions that have not seen activity in lets say 20 minutes?

This is considering that the user does not have internet connection as it would have contacted the database already and removed the session.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Write your cleanup method that removes old entries from database.

Create new worker thread, using ThreadPool, Tasks (TPL) or other technology (eg. HangFire). Call your cleanup method on this worker thread.

You can recreate worker thread periodically using Timer class, or by using library that has scheduling capabilities (see HangFire project for reference).

Comment: I'm going to give this a try. So the idea is to basically schedule a job for every x minutes that will retrieve the users license and keep recreating the job in a back thread as the user shows activity? @josef